# "development mode" with jsmp bundle-sfx

Tags: reactjs, jspm

Is there any way to get jspm bundle-sfx to build without setting NODE_ENV to production? I'd like to set it to development for better error messages (specifically with React, which is defaulting to some 'minimized' production mode).

Have tried this with no results:

```
NODE_ENV=dev `npm bin`/jspm bundle-sfx [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

jspm 0.17 will do this by default with the `jspm build` command (which replaces `jspm build-sfx` in 0.16) automatically treating it as a production build. `jspm build --dev` is then the way to do development-specific builds. I'd suggest trying the upgrade path if you can - the Beta release is quite stable at this point. See http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/index.html for more info.

Comment: Sorry I mean that the `--dev` flag in jspm 0.17 provides exactly what you're asking for here.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything working with a debug flag: https://gist.github.com/yodaiken/d59a8b7ccd726d4bb33b Still giving me the production version of React

Comment: And when I try a different command, different error: https://gist.github.com/yodaiken/a33d0e5f52079b2c76db

Comment: Which version of jspm beta is this with? Make sure you're running 0.17.0-beta.9.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm running.

Comment: Wow, yes that's a bug, fixed in https://github.com/systemjs/builder/commit/0efab54eba30688a901c553a635dbd5ba5a0fafe.